# If $X$ contains a countable dense subset, then $A$ denumerable or finite.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $\{ V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of nonempty open sets in $X$ which satisfies $V_{\alpha} \cap V_{\beta} = \emptyset $ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$ in $A$.

Prove that if $X$ is separable, then $A$ is countable.

attempt: Suppose that  $\{ V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of nonempty open sets in $X$ which satisfies $V_{\alpha} \cap V_{\beta} = \emptyset $ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$ in $A$. And suppose that $X$ is separable, then by definition, there is a countable set $Z$ of  $X$ such that for every $a \in X$, there is a sequence $x_k \in Z$ such that $x_k → a$ as $k → \infty$.
Then since $V_{\alpha} \cap V_{\beta} = \emptyset $ , then it contains points of the set $Z$, such that they are different values so injective. Thus, we can construct a bijection between the sets of open sets to the Z's , so it becomes a subset of Z. Since any subset of $Z$ is also countable, then $A$ is also countable, thus there is a bijection to the natural numbers.

Can someone please help me? I don't really know if this works. I was also thinking in using Lindelof's theorem but them I don't really know how to use the given hypothesis.  Any feedback or better approach would be really appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. Let $D_0 = D \cap \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_{\alpha}$. Then $D_0$ is countable since it is a subset of $D$.

Define a map $f: D_0 \to A$ by defining $f(x)$ to be the unique $\alpha \in A$ such that $x \in V_{\alpha}$. Such an $\alpha$ is unique by the disjointness of the collection $\{V_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in A}$.

I claim that $f$ is surjective. Indeed, if $\alpha \in A$, then by denseness of $D$ and openness of $V_{\alpha}$, there exists $x_{\alpha} \in D$ such that $x_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha}$, and then we clearly have that $f(x_{\alpha})=\alpha$.

Thus there exists a surjection from a countable set onto $A$, so $A$ must be countable.

Comment: user Shalop : So it is not necessary to mention $V_{\alpha} \cap V_{\beta}  =  \emptyset $? for all alpha and beta not equal in A?

Comment: It is definitely necessary: read the sentence "Such an $\alpha$ is unique by disjointness of the collection $\{V_{\beta}\}$." Without that condition, the map $f$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Thank you, it makes sense.